# Retrieving the amount of vertices/edges/faces in a QMesh (QT6)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt3d, qt6

This topic is a copy of [the topic I made on the QT Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/135012/retrieving-the-amount-of-vertices-edges-faces-in-a-qmesh-qt6) (which seems to be less active).

---

I'm having trouble to count the cells (vertices/edges/faces) of a `QMesh`, using Qt3DRender in QT6.

**Goal :** given a `Qt3DRender::QMesh`, retrieve its amount of vertices, edges and faces.

**Example :** For a simple cube, I'd like to retrieve 8/12/6

It seems that [the `vertexCount` method of the `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer` class function is designed for this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3drender-qgeometryrenderer.html#vertexCount-prop).

A `Qt3DRender::QMesh` is a `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer` so I decided to use `vertexCount`. Here comes the problem => it always returns 0.

**Context when calling `vertexCount` :**

- The loading state of the QMesh on which I'm calling `vertexCount` is `Qt3DRender::QMesh::Ready`
- I tried to parse the vertices positions of the `Qt3DCore::QGeometry` associated to the `QMesh` to count its vertices => it works (that is, the geometry is loaded too)

**Questions :**

- What is a "primitive" in the `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer` terminology? The function `vertexCount` definition is "holds the primitive count". I assumed that a "primitive" is either a vertex, an edge or a face (since this is what the `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::PrimitiveType` enumeration is).
- Is there any example using this function? I found nothing on the Internet nor in the Qt examples bank.